# Select box focus bug using -moz-transform in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I've noticed that if I apply a transform on a select box focus (i.e. select:focus) in Firefox it first focuses the select box then you must click the select box again for it to actually drop down.  Anyone else experience this?  I tried looking for a bug at Mozilla but didn't see anything.

Webkit browsers (tested in chrome) act appropriately.

I'm on Firefox 3.6.7

Test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    select:focus {
      -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select>
      <option>One</option>
      <option>Two</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've opened a bug at mozilla https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=581604

Comment: I confirm your behavior you are experiencing.

Comment: Also happens for me on 3.6.8 and 4.0 beta1

Comment: Confirm. Having this bug on FF 4.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is still not fixed, but this [workaround](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=581604#c4) works:

<sub>Add to CSS:</sub>

```
select { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
```

Comment: This is the best solution I've seen until they fix the bug, but at least for me it still shows some weird artifacts with the text.

Answer (score 0):

the -webkit-transform might be overwriting it
try removing it and see what happens
or seeing if regular transform works yet

Comment: I highly doubt that. The vendor specific tags are ignored by other browsers. This is why `-webkit-border-radius` does nothing in FF.

Answer (score 0):

We're in 2016 and the bug is always here... Even with

```css
select { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
```