# -moz-transform deactivates sorting select field in datatable header

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, datatables

I have a jQuery datatable generated in my webpage. Since it was too big, I used `zoom:0.8;` to fix its size in Google Chrome.

This didn't do it for Firefox though, so I added `-moz-transform: scale(0.8);` to the CSS sheet. Everything still works fine in Chrome, but if Firefox now shows the datatable correctly, it seems I cannot change the `sorting` value anymore in the header. I can click to see the list of items, but I cannot click them (nothing happens). I did not modify anything else than adding one line to my css file.

How can I fix this?

[jsbin](http://live.datatables.net/etacop/edit#preview)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ff7GF)

Note: There is a [similar known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=455170) filled at Bugzilla, although it was reported in 2008 and still is not fixed. It would be interesting to find a way around this issue.

Comment: I am on firefox 14.0.1 and I am not able to change the value of the `select` box; even in your jsfiddle example.

Comment: I can only select a value if I click on an option in the list, such that the cursor is to the right of the left border of the select box. The issue seems to be that the list does not move although the select box does (because the div gets smaller with the zooming).

Comment: Found here [similar, but different question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322050/select-box-focus-bug-using-moz-transform-in-firefox), but that solution seems not to work in this case. Also on [bugzilla](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Abugzilla.mozilla.org+moz+transform+bug+on+select+box) this error is already reported: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=744951

Comment: The bug you linked is a dupplicate of the bug I listed in the description up here. I tried changing the scale of the `select option` but it is still hovering to the left.

Comment: I think you could fix that `select` simply by moving the `#example_length` div out from `div.table` before it. So the transform will not be applied to the select. If it is possible on your page.

Comment: @Stano Since it is the `select` coming from the datatables library, your idea made me think of another way: I will create an independant `select` otuside the datatable (like you said), and I'll just make the `.change()` even trigger a datatable refresh with the new `iDisplayLength` attribute being the selected value!

Comment: Good idea Ghillied, I am also glad that you found a way how to make it work! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted the `l` from my `sDom` property when declaring the first instance of my datatable.

Then, I added this just before the `<table>` tag in my code:

```
<div class="selectLength">
    <span>Show</span>
    <select id="Length">
        <option value='5'>5</option>
        <option value='10'>10</option>
        <option value='25'>25</option>
        <option value='50'>50</option>
    </select>
    <span>elements in the datatable.</span>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript associated to this ([jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) is needed):

```
$('#Length').change(function() {
    var displayLength = $('#Length option:selected').val();
    var oSettings = $('.adminTable').dataTable().fnSettings();
    oSettings.iDisplayLength = displayLength;
    $('.adminTable').dataTable().fnDraw();
});
```